# Flutter doctor Command shows "unable to confirm if Installed Windows versions is 10 or greater)

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

as shown above I have every thing correctly installed for Flutter v3.7.8 but the Flutter dotor command shows the message "Windows Version (Unable to confirm if installed Windows version is 10 or greater)"

[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3KbT.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmdSe.png)

is it a missing component ?
how to fix it

I have every thing correctly installed for Flutter v3.7.8, I even reinstalled the android studio command line tool
and as shown on other answers I tried also the flutter clean command